# On the Kafka Java consumer client, is there a way to monitor health status as opposed to simply no-data?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a typical kafka consumer/producer app that is polling all the time for data.  Sometimes, there might be no data for hours, but sometimes there could be thousands of messages per second.  Because of this, the application is built so it's always polling, with a 500ms duration timeout.

However, I've noticed that sometimes, if the kafka cluster goes down, the consumer client, once started, won't throw an exception, it will simply timeout at 500ms, and continue returning empty `ConsumerRecords<K,V>`. So, as far as the application is concerned, there is no data to consume, when in reality, the whole Kafka cluster could be unreachable, but the app itself has no idea.

I checked the docs, and I couldn't find a way to validate consumer health, other than maybe closing the connection and subscribing to the topic every single time, but I really don't want to do that on a long-running application.

What's the best way to validate that the consumer is active and healthy while polling, ideally from the same thread/client object, so that the app can distinguish between no data and an unreachable kafka cluster situation?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the reconnect code.

What framework and versions are involved?

Comment: Does this behaviour change when using larger timeouts? A timeout of 500ms might not be long enough for the consumer to notice if the cluster is down. This could be the reason why no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is **not the best way** to achieve what you are looking for.

But one simple way which I had implemented in my application is by maintaining a static **counter** in the application indicating `emptyRecordSetReceived`. Whenever I receive an empty record set by the poll operation I increment this counter.

This counter was emitted to the Graphite at periodic interval (say every minute) with the help of the Metric registry from the application.

Now let's say you know the maximum time frame for which the message will not be available to consume by this application. For example, say 6 hours. Given that you are polling every 500 Millisecond, you know that if we do not receive the message for 6 hours, the counter would increase by

```
2 poll in 1 second * 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 6 hours = 43200.
```

We had placed an **alerting check** based on this counter value reported to Graphite. This metric used to give me a decent idea if it is a genuine problem from the application or something else is down from the Broker or producer side.

This is just the **naive way** I had solved this use case to some extent. I would love to hear how it is actually done without maintaining these counters.